# Earned badge and next badge is same. Possible bug

Tags: bug, badges

I take a look in to a person's profile and I saw that he earned the Curios badge yesterday. So, it shows his Latest Badge as Curious and the Next badge is also Curious.

[image]

I rechecked and the Badge awarded yesterday.

[image]

Is this a Bug or it happens because the user didn't Picked the badge?

Comment: They just haven't picked a different badge yet.

Comment: If you sure, please change tag to [tag:status-bydesign] @MartijnPieters

Comment: I can't be 100% sure yet, but I'm 99% sure that that's the cause.